# Setting min/max on ion-datetime component does not work with 12-hour clock; am/pm column

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, ionic4, ionic5

I am using ion-datetime and I have set min and max property for restrict time selection.

```
      <ion-datetime display-format="hh:mm A" picker-format="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="fromtime"
        [max]="totime">
        
        <ion-datetime display-format="hh:mm A" picker-format="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="totime"
        [min]="fromtime">
```

When I select in from time before 12 am then min property is working properly for totime. If i am selecting to time after 12 pm then picker is blank and not getting any data.
Does anyone have solution for this ?
Thank you

[image]

```
Ionic:
Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
@angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:
Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 6 other plugins)
```

Comment: I believe that what you're attempting to do will only work properly if you set the picker format to 24hr time like this `picker-format="H:mm"`